# How to perform Booking and generating Itinerary Id using expedia api?

Tags: php, json, api

I am using Expedia API for hotel booking.

It works perfectly but when i trying to get Itinerary Id using API tester By EAN.But, It gives error and cannot proceed for booking hotels.

Can you Please give me any Idea how can a integrate secure booking and cancellation of booking using EAN(Expedia Affiliate Network) API.

AND the error is as follow.

```
<HotelRoomReservationRequest>
<hotelId>106347</hotelId>
<arrivalDate>11/30/2013</arrivalDate>
<departureDate>12/2/2013</departureDate>
<supplierType>E</supplierType>
<rateKey>af00b688-acf4-409e-8bdc-fcfc3d1cb80c</rateKey>
<roomTypeCode>198058</roomTypeCode> 
<rateCode>484072</rateCode>
<chargeableRate>231.18</chargeableRate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this url

```
devhub.ean.com/apitester/index.html
```

After using this link.
Click on book reservation tab at the top. Then change in predefine xml code.
Use hotel id and make sure room type code and rate code will be according to that hotels room and not mismatch.

Comment: Thanks , Error was solved but it gives an another error right now that states "price mismatch".

Comment: which price from room availability 
you are using right now ?

Comment: I am using Average Base rate from charageble rate info.

Comment: use total rate from chargeable rate info. and try again. i hope this work :)